# Cannot place the dots in the centre of the squares, nor get the board to go ontop of the background and under the board

Tags: javascript

Basically, I am trying to make a board game, I am trying to make the dots being placed inside the squares, and the board covers it. The problem with the circles is that it goes under the board, and doesn't show.

I tried, but the board just fills the dots placed on it, I tried and placed it on the side and it worked.

```
//global variables
let gameBoard           //holds information about the state of the board      
let size = 15          //horz and vert size of the board

//runs once at the start
function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight)
    gameBoard = createBoard(size)
    
}

function draw() {

    //  background(220, 0, 0)
    //   translate(windowWidth / 2 - size / 2 * 30, windowHeight / 2 - size / 2 * 30)
    for (let x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        for (let y = 0; y < size; y++) {
            gameBoard[x][y].draw()
        }
    }
}

function createBoard(size) {

    function mousePressed() {
        fill('green')
        circle(mouseX, mouseY, 20)
        console.log('pressed', mouseX, mouseY)
    }
    
    let board = []
    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        let row = []
        for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            let square = new SQUARE(i, j)
            row.push(square)
        }
        board.push(row)
    }
    return board;
}

function mousePressed() {
    background(100,20,20)
    fill('green')
    circle(mouseX, mouseY, 20)
    console.log('pressed', mouseX, mouseY)
}
```

```
class SQUARE {

    constructor(column, row) {
        this.x = column
        this.y = row
    }

    draw() {
        fill('white')
        rect(this.x * 30, this.y * 30, 30, 30)
    }
}
```

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="p5.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="Square.js"></script>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="Wood020_4K_Color.png" />
  </body>
</html>
```